# What is the rigorous definition of rotating and reflecting square matrices?

Tags: matrices, definition

Suppose I have an $n \times n$ square matrix. I can think of it as a square array of numbers, or perhaps other objects. However, just as we can rotate squares and also reflect them, can we also do the same with square matrices? Basically, what is the rigorous definition of when two square matrices $M$ and $N$ are equivalent up to rotation, reflection, or a composition of a rotation and reflection?

Comment: These have no intrinsic meaning in terms of the underlying linear transformation unless you reflect across the main diagonal (so you're transposing the matrix).

Comment: @TedShifrin I know that, but I am asking for a definition of rotating square matrices, nothing to do with linear transformations per se, merely the matrix itself. Basically, what is the rigorous definition of the function that takes a square matrix and rotates it 90 degrees.

Comment: Rotation about the center of the square? The formula (in terms of $i,j$) will depend on the parity of $n$. What reflection do you have in mind? As I already said, reflection across the main diagonal just switches $i$ and $j$.